# What is the request rate limit for the Microsoft Academic API?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

What is the request rate limit for the Microsoft Academic API? I cannot seem to find it documented anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is 10,000 transactions per month for the free tier as stated [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/academic-knowledge-api/) and 3 per second for interpret, 1 per second for evaluate, 6 per minute for calcHistogram as stated [here](https://dev.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/products/5636d970e597ed0690ac1b3f)

**UPDATE**

The Cognitive Service Academic Knowledge API was rebranded to Project Academic Knowledge API which can be accessed through [this](https://msr-apis.portal.azure-api.net/products) link for more details.

Microsoft Academic Services documentation can be accessed through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic-services/) link.

**UPDATE**

It was announced on May 4, 2021 that Microsoft Academic website and underlying APIs will be retired on Dec. 31, 2021 as stated in [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/academic/articles/microsoft-academic-to-expand-horizons-with-community-driven-approach/) blog post.

> Microsoft Research will continue to support the automated AI agents
> powering Microsoft Academic services through the end of calendar year
> 2021. During this time, we encourage existing Microsoft Academic users to begin transitioning to other equivalent services. Below are just a
> few of the many great options available to the community.
>
> - [Aminer](https://www.aminer.org/)
> - [CrossRef](https://www.crossref.org/)
> - [Dimensions](https://www.dimensions.ai/)
> - [lens.org](https://www.lens.org/)
> - [OpenCitations](https://opencitations.net/)
> - [Scopus](https://www.scopus.com/)
> - [Semantic Scholar](https://www.semanticscholar.org/)

> What this means for each service:
>
> - Microsoft Academic Website: No longer accessible after Dec. 31, 2021
> - Project Academic Knowledge: No longer accessible after Dec. 31, 2021
> - Microsoft Academic Graph/Microsoft Academic Knowledge Exploration    Service: No longer providing updated data or access to old releases
>   after Dec. 31, 2021; however, existing copies can still be used under
>   license.

Comment: These links no longer lead to the information. Has anybody got updated information?

Comment: Apologies the info is there upon login. Can anyone tell me what a ‘transaction’ includes? I am interested to know if this is the same as a call to the API, and if this includes bulk calls (eg sending multiple IDs in a single call)?

Comment: @user1222447 I updated the answer with some updates, you can find correct links now, given that the request rate limit is still the same. And you are correct, it is a REST API. You can pass multiple `attributes` when using `CalcHistogram` if that is what you are referring to with "multiple Ids".

Answer (score 0):

You can select the api you want from **[here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/face-api/)**

and check the price

Up to 20 transactions per minute    30,000 transactions free per month

Comment: It is actually not listed there, as it still seems to be in some sort of semi-beta status through Labs. I have found https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/academic-knowledge-api/ but it does not list rate limits.